# global transition on exception and transition not found

Tags: spring, spring-webflow

I have 3 spring web-flows - flow1, flow2, flow3. flow2 and flow 3 have assigned parent flow1 like this :

```
<flow xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow
http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow/spring-webflow-2.0.xsd"
  parent="flow1">
```

In flow1 i have a global-transition and an end-state :

```
<end-state id="flowInterrupted" view="flowInterruptedPage"/>

<global-transitions>
    <transition on-exception="com.core.exceptions.policy.InvalidPolicyContactException" to="flowInterrupted">
        <evaluate expression="webFlowService.clearCurrentInterruptCause()"/>
    </transition>
</global-transitions>
```

At some point in my application, in flow2 a subflow flow3 is called

```
<subflow-state id="stateInFlow2WhereSubFlow3IsDefined" subflow="flow3">

</subflow-state>
```

, and in flow3, an InvalidPolicyContactException is thrown. It is properly found in flow1 (as its get's to clearCurrentInterruptCause()) but later an exception is thrown, that the flowInterrupted transition is not found in flow2 - and that's true, cause it's in flow1 (where the global-transition is defined). Here is the exception :

```
org.springframework.webflow.engine.NoMatchingTransitionException: No      transition found on occurence of event 'flowInterrupted'  in state 'stateInFlow2WhereSubFlow3IsDefined' of flow 'flow2' -- valid transitional criteria are array<TransitionCriteria>[exit, contactSelected] -- likely programmer error, check the set of TransitionCriteria for this state at org.springframework.webflow.engine.TransitionableState.getRequiredTransition(TransitionableState.java:93) at org.springframework.webflow.engine.TransitionableState.handleEvent(TransitionableState.java:119)
at org.springframework.webflow.engine.SubflowState.handleEvent(SubflowState.java:116)
at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Flow.handleEvent(Flow.java:555)
at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.handleEvent(FlowExecutionImpl.java:388)
at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.RequestControlContextImpl.handleEvent(RequestControlContextImpl.java:210)
at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.endActiveFlowSession(FlowExecutionImpl.java:412)
at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.RequestControlContextImpl.endActiveFlowSession(RequestControlContextImpl.java:238)
```

When I change end-state id="flowInterrupted" to view-state it works fine. when it's called from other flows, that have flow1 as parent it works also fine. When I remove parent=flow1 from flow3, I wouldn't catch an exceptin on global-transition. The only problem is, when an exception is raised from a subflow.

Any help would be appreciated - I can of course put flowInterrupted state in flow2 and solve the problem, but I would like to understand, why this is happening

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

add
`<transition on="flowInterrupted" to="flowInterrupted"/>`
in your global transition